# Flutter Widget Test - Can't seem to test for condition

Tags: flutter, testing, widget

I have an issue with testing the decoration matching when `_errorText` is not `null`. Even thought when I print the logs in the test if the `_errorText` has value and it does, the decoration which I'm expecting doesn't seem to match. It still assumes the box decoration is:

```
BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.white,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  border: Border.all(
    color: Colors.black45,
    width: 1.5,
  ),
)
```

instead of:

```
BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.red.shade200,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  border: Border.all(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 1.5,
  ),
)
```

However in the app it does switch from white to red when there's an error.

Stateless Widget:

```
  // Variables and Constructor

  String? get _errorText => formKey.currentState?.fields[fieldName]?.errorText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 15.0,
        vertical: 10.0,
      ),
      decoration: _errorText == null
          ? BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black45,
                width: 1.5,
              ),
            )
          : BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red.shade200,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 55.0,
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          prefix ?? const SizedBox(),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: prefix != null ? 10.0 : 0.0,
                right: suffix != null ? 10.0 : 0.0,
              ),
              child: FormBuilderTextField(
                key: key,
                name: fieldName,
                // other params
              ),
            ),
          ),
          suffix ?? const SizedBox(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Test:

```
void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    _setupDependencies();
    _commonSetup();
  });

  group(
    'StyledTextField Tests',
    () {
      testWidgets(
        'Test StyledTextField with error renders correctly',
        (tester) async {
          const errorText = 'Field is required';
          when(_formUtility.formKey).thenReturn(GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>());

          await tester.pumpWidget(
            MaterialApp(
              home: Material(
                child: FormBuilder(
                  key: _formUtility.formKey,
                  child: StyledTextField(
                    formKey: _formUtility.formKey,
                    fieldName: _TestFieldName.error.name,
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(
                      errorText: errorText,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );

          await tester.tap(find.byType(StyledTextField));
          await tester.pump();

          final foundContainer = find.byType(Container);
          final foundStyledTextField = find.byType(StyledTextField);

          final container = tester.widget<Container>(foundContainer);

          final decoration = container.decoration as BoxDecoration;
          final color = decoration.color as Color;
          final borderRadius = decoration.borderRadius as BorderRadius;
          final border = decoration.border as Border;

          expect(foundContainer, findsOneWidget);
          expect(foundStyledTextField, findsOneWidget);
          expect(find.text(errorText), findsOneWidget);
          expect(color, Colors.red.shade200);
          expect(borderRadius, BorderRadius.circular(10.0));
          expect(border, Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1.5));
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```